# Prevent chrome from adding a border around edited textareas of a pdf when printing

Tags: css, pdf, printing, tcpdf

I created a custom PDF using TCPDF. This pdf had a textarea with some prepopulated values. When i try to print them in chrome the text area don't have a border. But if I edit the values in the text area and try to print, a border appears around the textarea. I see the same behavior in firefox and adobe acrobat also. How to prevent this. I suspect this is a client issue as i did not have the issue when i opened the pdf and edited using libra office draw.

I have tried each of the following separately as styles when creating the pdf with TCPDF. But none of them worked.

```
@media print {
    textarea {
        font-size: 13px;
        outline: none !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        -moz-appearance: none !important;
        appearance: none !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
@media print {
    textarea:focus {
        font-size: 13px;
        outline: none !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        -moz-appearance: none !important;
        appearance: none !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
textarea {
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
}
```